# Stacking/rearranging every 2 values in a row into 2 columns, row by row, in a dataframe on R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I hope I can explain myself to the point my problem make sense! Been stuck on this one for hours.

What I have: a dataframe where the columns are genes (gene a, gene b, gene c, etc.) and the rows are cell clusters in two conditions (cluster a_ctrl, cluster a_exp, clusterb_ctrl, etc.)

What I want: I want it the other way around (but not transposed!) so that the columns are clusters (cluster a, cluster b, cluster c, etc.) and the rows are genes in two conditions (gene a_ctrl, gene a_exp, gene b_ctrl, etc.)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It will be easier for people to test and share solutions if you can share in your question some fake data that makes the data structure explicit, and where you can show the exact desired result.

Answer (score 0):

First, some fake data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(cluster = c("clustera_ctrl", "clustera_exp", "clusterb_ctrl", "clusterb_exp"),
           gene_a = 1:4,
           gene_b = 5:8,
           gene_c = 9:12)

        cluster gene_a gene_b gene_c
1 clustera_ctrl      1      5      9
2  clustera_exp      2      6     10
3 clusterb_ctrl      3      7     11
4  clusterb_exp      4      8     12
```

Approach using separate, pivot_longer, and pivot_wider from `tidyr`. I think there's a shorter way with one `pivot_longer` but this should be clear enough.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  separate(cluster, c("cluster", "type"), sep = "_") %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("gene")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(name, type), values_from = value)


# A tibble: 2 × 7
  cluster  gene_a_ctrl gene_b_ctrl gene_c_ctrl gene_a_exp gene_b_exp gene_c_exp
  <chr>          <int>       <int>       <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
1 clustera           1           5           9          2          6         10
2 clusterb           3           7          11          4          8         12
```